# Create decimal and non decimal axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library("scales")

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(col1 = seq(0.0001,10,0.01))
df$col2 <-runif(100)

ggplot(df, aes(col1, col2)) +          
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0.0001,0.01,0.1,1,5,10), 
                     limits=c(0.0001,10))
```

In the above code, I want to see decimals for breaks below 1 but no decimals on higher values.
The x-axis label should not show decimals for 1,5 and 10

Is this possible in ggplot to have mix of decimal and non-decimal labels[image]?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a function to the `labels` argument which using `ifelse` conditionally sets the accuracy or the number of decimal dpeneding on the value of the break:

```r
library("scales")

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(col1 = seq(0.0001,10,0.01))
df$col2 <-runif(100)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(col1, col2)) +          
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0.0001,0.01,0.1,1,5,10), 
                     labels =  ~ ifelse(.x < 1, label_number(accuracy = .0001)(.x), label_number(accuracy = 1)(.x)),
                     limits=c(0.0001,10))
```

[image]