# Dynamic decimal precision in ggplot axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to display only the minimum number of decimal places in my `ggplot` axis labels (e.g. `0.1` with `10` as opposed to `10.0`. I was trying to get `scales::label_number()` to do this, but the `accuracy` argument is applied across all of the labels. Also I'd like to be able to add `big.mark = ","` if possible.

The closest [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71591217/13210554) I found suggests an `ifelse` function to dynamically round as needed but it feels a little clunky. Is there some slick way to do this with {scales} or similar?

Minimal example with current and desired results:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

# current labels with scales::label_number()
tibble(x = -2:3, y = 10^x) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Undesriable: same precision on all labels") +
  scale_y_log10(labels = label_number(big.mark = ","), breaks = 10^(-2:3))
```

[image]

```r
# desired labels manually specified
tibble(x = -2:3, y = 10^x) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Desriable: minimum needed precision on each label with comma") +
  scale_y_log10(labels = c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, "1,000"), breaks = 10^(-2:3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `I` seems pretty neat to me:

```r
tibble(x = -2:3, y = 10^x) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_log10(labels = I, breaks = 10^(-2:3))
```

[image]

Though if you wanted a bit more control, then you could use `prettyNum` - e.g.

```r
tibble(x = -2:3, y = 10^x) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_log10(labels = ~ prettyNum(.x, big.mark = ","), breaks = 10^(-2:3))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, hard to improve on the parsimony of that! Is there any way to combine this with `scales::label_number()` to get the benefits of things like `big.mark = ","`?

Comment: @DanAdams an alternative would be `labels = ~ prettyNum(.x, big.mark = ","))`

Comment: I like `scales::label_number_si` as another new option, it makes 1000 into 1K and 1000000 into 1B.

Comment: @AllanCameron - Yes `prettyNum` was what I was looking for. I will add this extra point to my question if you don't mind updating your answer to include this option too for others to benefit from your wisdom. Thanks!

Comment: And actually what I really wanted here was `labels = ~prettyNum(.x, big.mark = ",", scientific = F)` to avoid the scientific notation.